Using modheader to Modify Headers in Selenium with Robot Framework
I'm trying to use the modheader extension to modify headers in Chrome through Selenium in Robot Framework. I've created a custom library in Python to handle this, but I'm facing an issue with accessing the localStorage when I try to modify headers.
Here's the Python code I wrote for the custom library:
from SeleniumLibrary.base import keyword
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
import sys

class ChromeDriverLib:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    @property
    def get_lib(self):
        return BuiltIn().get_library_instance('SeleniumLibrary')

    @keyword(name='Open Browser With Headers')
    def open_the_browser_with_headers(self, url="DEFAULT_URL", browser="chrome", remote_url=False, header="DEFAULT_HEADER", value="DEFAULT_VALUE", header2="DEFAULT_HEADER", value2="DEFAULT_VALUE", header3="DEFAULT_HEADER", value3="DEFAULT_VALUE", download_dir="DEFAULT_DIR"):
        browser_options = sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()
        browser_options.add_extension('./modheader.crx')
        browser_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
        browser_options.add_argument("--kiosk")
        browser_options.add_argument("enable-features=NetworkServiceInProcess")
        browser_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
        browser_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
            "download.default_directory": download_dir,
            "download.prompt_for_download": False,
            "download.directory_upgrade": True,
            "safebrowsing.enabled": True
        })
        browser_options = browser_options.to_capabilities()
        self.get_lib.open_browser("chrome-extension://idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj/icon.png", browser, None, remote_url, browser_options, None)
        self.get_lib.driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
        self.get_lib.driver.execute_script(
            "localStorage.setItem('profiles', JSON.stringify([{title: 'Selenium', hideComment: true, appendMode: '', headers: [{enabled: true, name: '" + header + "', value: '" + value + "', comment: ''}, {enabled: true, name: '" + header2 + "', value: '" + value2 + "', comment: ''}, {enabled: true, name: '" + header3 + "', value: '" + value3 + "', comment: ''}], respHeaders: [], filters: []}]))"
        )
        return self.get_lib.go_to(url)

I'm calling this library in my Robot Framework test case as follows:
Library    mypython.py
Open Browser With Headers    url=${url}    browser=chrome    header=myheader    value=myvalue    header2=myheader2    value2=myvalue2    header3=myheader3    value3=myvalue3    download_dir=mydownloadir

When executing the test, I get a JavascriptException with the message:
Message: javascript error: {"status":18,"value":"Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document."}

Can anyone help resolve this error or suggest a workaround for modifying headers using modheader in this setup?
